AWS S3 SDK v2 Upload Adds Random String Prefix to JSON File
I'm using the AWS SDK v2 for Java to upload JSON data to an S3 bucket. However, after the upload, the file in S3 contains a random string prefix and the JSON data appears to be incomplete or corrupted. Here is the relevant part of my implementation:
Using s3AsyncClient or transferManager return the same result.
import software.amazon.awssdk.core.async.BlockingInputStreamAsyncRequestBody;
import software.amazon.awssdk.core.sync.RequestBody;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.s3.S3AsyncClient;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.s3.S3Client;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.s3.model.PutObjectRequest;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.s3.model.PutObjectResponse;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.s3.model.S3Exception;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.s3.presigner.S3Presigner;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.s3.presigner.model.GetObjectPresignRequest;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.s3.presigner.model.PresignedGetObjectRequest;
import software.amazon.awssdk.transfer.s3.S3TransferManager;
import software.amazon.awssdk.transfer.s3.model.CompletedUpload;
import software.amazon.awssdk.transfer.s3.model.Upload;

public class S3ServiceImpl implements S3Service {
  @Override
    public CompletedUpload uploadStream(String key, InputStream stream) throws FileNotFoundException {
        BlockingInputStreamAsyncRequestBody body =
                AsyncRequestBody.forBlockingInputStream(null); // 'null' indicates a stream will be provided later.
        S3TransferManager transferManager = S3TransferManager.builder()
                .s3Client(s3AsyncClient)
                .build();
        Upload upload = transferManager.upload(builder -> builder
                .requestBody(body)
                .putObjectRequest(req -> req.bucket(bucketName).key(key))
                .build());

        body.writeInputStream(stream);

        return upload.completionFuture().join();
    }

    @Override
    public CompletableFuture<PutObjectResponse> uploadStream(String key, InputStream stream) {
        BlockingInputStreamAsyncRequestBody body =
                AsyncRequestBody.forBlockingInputStream(null); // 'null' indicates a stream will be provided later.

        CompletableFuture<PutObjectResponse> responseFuture =
                s3AsyncClient.putObject(r -> r.bucket(bucketName).key(key), body);

        body.writeInputStream(stream);

        return responseFuture;
    }
}



 @Override
@Async
public void export(Query query) {
    try {
        PipedInputStream pipedInputStream = new PipedInputStream();
        PipedOutputStream pipedOutputStream = new PipedOutputStream(pipedInputStream);
        executorService.submit(() -> exportToPipe(query, pipedOutputStream));
        CompletedUpload completedUpload = s3Service.uploadStream(task.getFileName(), pipedInputStream);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        log.error("export ERROR {}", "", e);
    }
}


private void exportToPipe(Query query, PipedOutputStream pipedOutputStream) {
    try (pipedOutputStream; OutputStreamWriter writer = new OutputStreamWriter(new BufferedOutputStream(pipedOutputStream), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
         Stream<Entity> entityStream= mongoOperations.stream(query, Entity.class)) {
        serializeEntityStream(entityStream, writer);
    } catch (IOException e) {}
}

the json file (after I download it), is not complete, missing few characters & the content starts with random characters like in this example :
A63
[{"id":1,"name":"apple","category":"fruit","price":0.5},{"id":2,"name":"banana","category":"fruit","price":0.3},{"id":3,"name":"carrot","category":"vegetable","price":0

if the file is large (14mb) than A63 is replaced with 800000 which makes me think that the characters are related to the size, (empty file will have "2" in it).

I tried writing to temp file (the temp file is correct) and then uploading using FileInputStream but had same result.
The issue seems related to AsyncS3Client only S3Client works as expected.
Even testing with the correct content-size based on file gives the same result.
Any ideas?


This is how async pipeline works. You should implement it correctly and wait until the transfer is completed.

@Mar-Z what do you mean by   "This is how async pipeline works" or "implement it correctly", maybe add more details to make the comment more helpful?

As I said: your code should wait for the transfer to complete. Asynchronous yes, but not just fire and forget.
